# How multithreaded Steps works internally while reading the flatfile?

Tags: spring-batch

I am looking to read Flatfile which is in 10 GB. For that, I chose to use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to make my step multi-threded.

I am wondering how these 4 worker threads are working internally? How one thread doesn't read the data read by another thread. If someone can explain how it's working internally, that will be great help.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Transaction> fileTransactionReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputFlatFile']}") Resource resource) {

        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Transaction>()
                .saveState(false)
                .resource(resource)
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[] {"account", "amount", "timestamp"})
                .fieldSetMapper(fieldSet -> {
                    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                    transaction.setAccount(fieldSet.readString("account"));
                    transaction.setAmount(fieldSet.readBigDecimal("amount"));
                    transaction.setTimestamp(fieldSet.readDate("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

                    return transaction;
                })
                .build();
    }
```

Code -

```
@Bean
public Job multithreadedJob() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("multithreadedJob")
            .start(step1())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();

    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Transaction, Transaction>chunk(100)
            .reader(fileTransactionReader(null))
            .writer(writer(null))
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FlatFileItemReader` is not in itself thread-safe as it extends `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` whose javadoc states `Subclasses are inherently not thread-safe`. So strictly speaking, you should wrap it in a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`. See also: [Can I use FlatfileItemReader with Taskexecutor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998974/can-i-use-flatfileitemreader-with-taskexecutor)

Having said that, if you

- don't care about restartability,
- don't care about the line numbers,
- don't use a mapping that would require state,
- set `saveState` to `false`,
- and don't change the reader's default `bufferedReaderFactory`,

then the reader is just a thin wrapper around

- a `BufferedReader` whose method `readLine` is called for each `FlatFileItemReader::read`,
- and a `LineMapper` that maps each line to the target type

And `BufferedReader` is thread-safe which makes your reader effectively safe to call in a multi-threaded step.

But beware: The Spring Batch API makes no promises about the thread-safety of the reader. Quite the opposite, actually. So, the multi-threaded behavior is at least in theory up to change in future versions. Furthermore, there are a lot of conditions listed above which someday may no longer hold for your implementation. Thus, using a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader` is really recommended.

See also [Can spring batch multi-threaded step be used safely if number of items in file are very less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183703/can-spring-batch-multi-threaded-step-be-used-safely-if-number-of-items-in-file-a)